# android custom listview row formatting question

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout

I have a listview that I am trying to customize. The issue I am having with eclipse's android plugin is I am not quite sure how to format the text portions and wrap them around my icon. Here is a diagram with what I am trying to do:

[image: toms custom row]

I need to know,

**1.** Advice on formatting text to fit the row. for the top, i want 3 different strings to fit (what they can) into their own column and ellipsise at the end. easy enough.

**2.** I want to do something similar for the bottom row but give it a max length. Say each column can contain up to 20 characters, including the (...) ellipses. it may contain 1-7 columns. So I want the overflow to go to the next row and wrap under the icon.

**3.** Perhaps someone has a war story with a custom listview they want to share? How did you fit all the information in the item, or did you use an alternate view such as GridView instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For point 1: You can use LinearLayouts for each row, using the weight property on each element according to your needs.
For point 3: in order to make the text to ellipsise you can use the property

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

although it has deprecated, or use

```
android:inputType
```

with anything in order to not set the textMultiLine flag into true

For point 2: i cant think of doing this in other way than programatically